# Abstract Data Type Pass as a parameter

Tags: c++, function, random, parameters, hashtable

Hey so I'm trying to pass a hash table as a parameter in c++, when I call the function that I am trying to run i get an error message that i do not understand.

So this is the function:

```
string getRandomKey(int tableNumber, int tableSize, HashTable<string>* table, int random){
    random *= rand() % tableSize + 1;
    string randKey = to_string(tableNumber) + to_string(random);

    if((table->find(randKey)) == true){
        cout << "Key: " << randKey << " found ";
        return randKey;
    }
    return "";  
}
```

This is by no means the final version I'm just trying to test it. Some context is that I have a couple of hash tables, and a separate integer variable that has the number of elements that i have predetermined. The keys are set to be one of the random numbers.

Anyway so here is where I call the function:

```
table1->print(getRandomkey(1, sizes[2], table1*, 1));
```

And I get this error:

```
error: expected expression
    table1->print(getRandomKey(1, sizes[2], table1*, 1));
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
```

So, I'm not sure what I need to change or if I messed something up somewhere else. Thanks for any help you guys can give!

Comment: What is `table11`? Is it a `HashTable<string>*`? Or is it a `HashTable<string>**`? Perhaps you should take some time [to read a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about pointers and the dereference operator?

Comment: Also, what is the reason to use a pointer instead of e.g. a *reference*? Preferably a reference to a `const` since you don't modify the table.

Comment: table1 is a HashTable<string>*. I forgot about references, do you think that would work better?

Comment: "table11*" is not valid C++. What do you expect to accomplish, here? Since the corresponding parameter is a pointer, you have to either pass a pointer here, or create a pointer to an existing object using the `&` operator.

Comment: Pointers should be avoided as much as possible. And in modern C++ you can almost do that, with the major exception of polymorphism.

Comment: I should have mentioned that in my actual code i didnt actually call it table1, that must have been a typo when i was changing it. So youre saying i should get rid of the number and use a reference &?

Comment: also, the actual character that the compiler had the ^ under was the comma in the function call ,

Comment: You know there's an *edit* link below the tags?

Comment: Oops, i edited it now. So just to be completely clear, you recommend using a reference in the function call and in the function keep the pointer? Or what combination of that would you say? Thanks for your help regardless by the way

Answer (score 1):

It appears that table1 is a pointer to a HashTable so when you
make the call to getRandomKey the term table1* should just be table1.

table1->print(getRandomkey(1, sizes[2], table1, 1));